# Different behavior of SetNativeControl in PageRenderer

Tags: xamarin, win-universal-app, xamarin.forms, windows-10-universal, xamarin.windows

I was using PageRenderer for native UWP (Universal Windows Platform) but it behaved weird which I didn't expect. I used following class to render a native page `MyUWP` to load in place of a Xamarin.Forms page

```
class MyUWPRenderer : PageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Page> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);


        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            // **** Element.Content = null;
            SetNativeControl(new MyUWP());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
        } 
    }
}
```

If I don't use `Element.Content = null;` in above code, both pages (Native and Xamarin.Forms) will be render on top of one another. So, I had to first set the Content to null to make native page visible.

Is there any reason behind it or am I understanding wrong?
The above similar code works in Xamarin.Android project very well.

Comment: In the most basic terms, the `Element` is the cross-platform representation of the control that goes onto the page. The `Element.Content` value for the Page is setting it to whatever layout's being used (let's say it's just a StackLayout). That Content is then converted into the platform-specific view. By setting the native control as well via `SetNativeControl`, you're presumably creating a secondary control/view which is separate from whatever is being created and rendered via the `Content` value.

Comment: But I think by the definition of `SetNativeControl` it should be overwriting the `Element`'s (page) values too. But it is actually displaying both on top of each other.